# Is there anyway for me to send a PDF and PNGs by text using MFMessageComposeViewController() in Swift?

Tags: swift

Whenever I try to use .addAttachmentURL, it does not attach anything. The ViewController is presented with nothing within the body of the text. The URL is a path to the pdf *data* (I don't know if that makes a difference) in my file defaults. Is there any way I can send a PDF through text like this? I have not found anything by looking through documentation or StackOverflow. Also, I haven't implemented it yet, but I was wondering if there was a way to also attach PNGs to this message I am sending along with the PDF.

```
func getFileManager() -> NSString {
        let filePath = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString)
        return filePath
    }


func displayMessageInterface() {
        let composeVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        composeVC.messageComposeDelegate = self
        
        // Configure the fields of the interface.
        composeVC.recipients = ["000000000"]
        var url = URL(string: self.getFileManager() as String)!
        url.appendPathComponent("my_report.pdf")
        composeVC.addAttachmentURL(url, withAlternateFilename: 
        "this file")
        
        // Present the view controller modally.
        if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() {
            self.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            print("Can't send messages.")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong URL initializer. `URL(string:)` initializer expects a scheme, in this case `file://`. You need to use `URL(fileURLWithPath:)` initializer or simply get the document directory URL using FileManager urls method:

```
extension URL {
    static let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
}
```

---

```
let url = URL.documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("my_report.pdf")
```

I am not sure what you mean when you say "The URL is a path to the pdf data in my file defaults". If you have included your file in your project Bundle you need to use its `url(forResource:)` method.

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "my_report", withExtension: "pdf")!
```

Comment: Oh I meant User Defaults. I'm new to swift, so I'm trying to learn everything on the fly. I think I understand what the Bundle is, but I know I have all my files saving to User defaults. So would I just not include the Bundle line?

Comment: You shouldn't use your UserDefaults for storing your app data. Just write the data to the document directory or at your application support directory. The Bundle is read only (only files that will be included in your app)